# How to add states onClick in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code which add and remove a class. But I want to add another class over the image when is active and remove it when is inactive. The problem is that I could added but is going to be active for all elements not only for the one is opened. Does anyone has an idea how to fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/bmhv3edw/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function close_answer_section() {
    $('.question-text').removeClass('active');
    $('.plus').attr("src","http://tdhtestserver.herobo.com/plus-eclipse.png");
    $('.answer-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
}

$('.question-text').click(function(e) {
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');
    if($(this).is('.active')) {
        close_answer_section();
    }else {
        close_answer_section();
        $(".plus").attr("src","http://tdhtestserver.herobo.com/plus-eclipse-active.png");
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.questions ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Comment: could you put this or an example in a  JSFiddle ?

Comment: there is a JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/bmhv3edw/2/

Comment: can give more specific info what you are trying to do?? which class to which tag, etc.

Comment: I want `$(this).addClass('eclipse');` to be over `<img src="http://tdhtestserver.herobo.com/plus-eclipse.png"/>` when `$(this).addClass('active');` now if you click on that plus icon you will be able to see a shadow somewhere on top of it because is active but behind it

Comment: @MarkusHayner My apologies, I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 function close_answer_section() {
  $('.question-text').removeClass('active');
        $('.plus').attr("src","http://tdhtestserver.herobo.com/plus-eclipse.png");
  $('.answer-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
 }

 $('.question-text').click(function(e) {
  var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');
  if($(this).is('.active')) {
   close_answer_section();
  }else {
   close_answer_section();

   $(this).find('img').attr("src","http://tdhtestserver.herobo.com/plus-eclipse-active.png");
        $(this).addClass("active");
   $('.questions ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
  }

  e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

```css
/* body{ background: black }; */
.questions{
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 170px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.question{
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.answer-section-content {
  display:none;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questions">
       <div class="question">
                                <div class="question-text" href="#answer-52"><img class="plus" src="http://tdhtestserver.herobo.com/plus-eclipse.png"/> Question 1</div>
        <div id="answer-52" class="answer-section-content">
         <p>Answer 1</p>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="question">
        <div class="question-text" href="#answer-53"><img class="plus" src="http://tdhtestserver.herobo.com/plus-eclipse.png"/> Question 2</div>
        <div id="answer-53" class="answer-section-content">
         <p>Answer 1</p>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this is going under. please have a look on this https://jsfiddle.net/bmhv3edw/3/ the issue is that is going to be active for all my elements

Comment: @MarkusHayner try this now.